# iOS Swift iPad orientation changed UIPagerViewController

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, orientation

I am trying to solve the following problem ON IPAD!

I want a dynamically created PagerViewController with 1 to n ViewController as childs!

This Problem i solved by:

```
func initialize() {
    orderedViewControllers = []

    let iCountPerPages = iCols*iRows

    var oViewController:UIPagerPage? = nil

    for oLayoutObject:LayoutObjectDto in lLayoutObject {

        if oViewController == nil || oViewController?.lLayoutObjects.count == iCountPerPages {
            if oViewController != nil {
                orderedViewControllers.append( oViewController! )
            }

            oViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("UIPagerPage") as? UIPagerPage
            oViewController?.iRows = self.iRows
            oViewController?.iCols = self.iCols
        }

        if oLayoutObject.isDataSource() {
            oViewController?.lLayoutObjects.append(oLayoutObject)
        }
    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.setViewControllers([self.orderedViewControllers.first!],
            direction: .Forward,
            animated: true,
            completion: nil)
    });

}
```

So now the first Problem:

I want that the UIPagerPage get a layout from 4 Cols ans 2 Rows on landscape and 2 Rows x 2 Cols on portrait.

By size-classes this problem is not solvable or? 
I solved this Problem by indicate the count of rows and cols by this:

```
enum ScreenTyp {
case PHONE_LANDSCAPE, PHONE_PORTRAIT, PAD_LANDSCAPE, PAD_PORTRAIT

static func getScreenTyp() -> ScreenTyp {
    if(UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone) {
        //Phone
        if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation==UIDeviceOrientation.Portrait {
            //Portrait
            return .PHONE_PORTRAIT
        } else {
            //Landscape
            return .PHONE_LANDSCAPE
        }
    } else {
        //Pad
        if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation==UIDeviceOrientation.Portrait {
            //Portrait
            return .PAD_PORTRAIT
        } else {
            //Landscape
            return .PAD_LANDSCAPE
        }
    }
}

static func isOrientationIsLandscape() -> Bool {
    return UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation.isLandscape
}

static func isOrientationIsPortrait() -> Bool {
    return UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation.isPortrait
}

}
```

And generate the Layout from UIPagerPage dynamic.

So but on rotation (from landscape to portrait) it is rotating but the layout is still 4x2 instead of 2x2.

So now i tryed to reload all pages on rotation, by this:

```
override func willRotateToInterfaceOrientation(toInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation, duration: NSTimeInterval) {
    self.initialize()
}
```

With this function i get an NSExeption, i think because the animation is still running this function works better:

```
override func didRotateToInterfaceOrientation(toInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) {
    self.initialize()
}
```

But the Page that is shown before rotation is still displayed!

Thank's

Comment: If you are using iOS8 and above try the following delegate for orientation change........override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation.isLandscape.boolValue {
        print("Landscape")
    } else {
        print("Portrait")
    }
}

Comment: Can you show us the exception message